# How to google for "extern void*"?

Tags: google-search, search

I want to search for a specific string that unfortunately contains google wildcards (`*`).

How can I search pages where the exact string `extern void*` appears.

*(Some of you might have guessed that I am wrestling with C these days)*

I tried with DuckDuckGo or Bing with the same result: the `*` is interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [cannot](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479) search for string containing `*` with Google: the character is ignored. See [replacement for Google Code Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7778034/395857) for searching code.